# The most amazing thing (was/were) the people who

Tags: verb-agreement

Which one is correct? 
The way I see it, the subject is 'the thing' which is singular thus it should carry 'was', no matter what follows. However, there seems to be a lot of people who use 'were' instead.
Is 'the people' the subject in this sentence?

Comment: The most amazing thing**s were** the people...

Comment: Verbs agree with their subject. The subject is generally the noun phrase before the first auxiliary verb, except in special constructions like questions. The subject here is singular third person, so the verb is _was_.

Comment: I cannot upvote you guys so I'll just say thank you.

Comment: @Ian MacDonald The '[most amazing] thing' here is generalised; 'things' does not work. Compare 'It's us'. The subject outranks the complement in dictating the agreement of the verb.

Answer (score 2):

Your point is right. The correct way is

> The most amazing thing **was** the people who...

I tried to think about the other specific possibilities. Sometimes we use "were" in the case of the subjunctive mood, however, it is used after "if, as if, wish, suppose". Here is not that case except if it is like

> (I wish) the most amazing thing **were** the people who...

"I wish" was not said, but meant.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As you noted, this is not a subjunctive sentence. Just plain old simple past.