# How do I choose between “was” and “were”?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage, verb-agreement, conundrum

Should I use the singular “was” or the plural “were”   in the following sentence?

> The first thing that I noticed **was** (OR) **were** the street performers singing near the main entrance of the park.

If I reversed the order, should the verb agree with its antecedent *the street performers*, which is a plural noun, or with singular noun “thing”?

> The street performers, singing near the main entrance of the park, **were** (OR) **was** the first thing I noticed.

I could change the singular *thing* into *things* but I am uncomfortable with saying “the performers” are “things”.

> The street performers, singing near the main entrance of the park, were the first *things* I noticed.

Comment: _It are us_ or _It is us_?

Comment: [About 255 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22first+thing+I+noticed+were%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books for ***the first thing I noticed*** (and hundreds more for ***next/only** thing **he/she/we/they** etc. etc*) suggest that it's as much a matter of style/nuance as anything.

Comment: @FF I'm very unhappy with the plural verb here. 'I noticed several things. The first thing were the street performers.'  It sounds very unnatural to my ears. I'm convinced that 'It is us' is archetypal.

Comment: Hi, Josh. Your question is on the verge of being closed because (1) you don't indicate why you think there may be an issue involving _was_ vs. _were_ in the example sentence, and (2) you don't report anything you've found out in researching the question before asking it here. Please consider adding some coverage of these points to your question.

Comment: @Edwin: There's a world of difference with your version - a straight SVO with nothing between the superficially singular subject and the verb itself. *And* you're skewing the contextual pragmatics by explicitly pointing out that "the first thing" is ***one of several***.

Comment: chasly, and Egmont at [Wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-first-thing-we-noticed-was-were.2361733/) (I can't find a more recognised authority) both agree that the acceptable agreement is 'grammatical' rather than 'proximal: complement' here. //// Ah! 4. When two nouns are connected by some form of the verb to be, the first noun is the
grammatical subject, and the verb agrees with it.
...
WRONG: The first [thing] we noticed were the [shoes]. /
CORRECT: The first [thing] we noticed was the [shoes]. /
CORRECT: The shoes were the first thing we noticed.

Comment: The above from [ClaremontGraduateUniversity](http://www.cgu.edu/PDFFiles/Writing%20Center/Writing%20Center%20Resources/Subject-Verb%20Agreement.pdf).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for posting the link from Claremont.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The most amazing thing (was/were) the people who](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233116/the-most-amazing-thing-was-were-the-people-who)

Answer (score 1):

'The first thing was ...' The subject of the verb 'to be' is 'thing.'

You could say, 'The first things were...' –